# php://ouput is not valid

Tags: php, http-headers, fopen

I am going to generate a csv file to php output, so the user can download it immediately:

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename );
$fp = fopen('php://ouput', 'w'); // Here is where error happens, line 156
if(!$fp) var_dump($fp); // output: bool(false)
```

but it produces the below errors:

```
Warning: fopen(): Invalid php:// URL specified in /home/mustafa/xxx/includes/functions.php on line 156
Warning: fopen(php://ouput): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/mustafa/xxx/includes/functions.php on line 156
```

Why `php://output` is not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
$fp = fopen('php://ouput', 'w');
```

to

```
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
                     ^ // you missed `t`
```

Answer (score 1):

`fopen()` write to a file. `php://ouput` is no a valid filename/URL. It is [php://output](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php), you are missing a 't'.

If you want to send your output to the client (browser), just print the data with `echo`.